# php xml get value of node

Tags: php

How can I get "bla" in the below dump of my node
Essentially bla is what is contained in my node

```
<mynode name="myvalueone" display="myvalue2">bla</mynode>


object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'myvalueone' (length=65)
      'display' => string 'myvalue2' (length=9)
  string 'bla' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the value by casting the SimpleXMLElement to a string like this: `$value = (string)$element;`

Comment: ah thank you! I had tried this but when I was doing a var_dump on the result it was giving me an SimpleXML Object but now I tried again and I see can cast that to a string.